# Error: Cannot find module 'react/lib/Object.assign' from dispatcher

Tags: reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

Below is my dispatcher code

```
var Dispatcher = require("flux").Dispatcher;
var assign = require("react/lib/Object.assign");

var AppDispatcher = assign(new Dispatcher(), {
    handleViewAction: function(action){
        console.log('action', action)
        this.dispatch({
            source: 'VIEW_ACTION',
            action: action
        })
    }
});

module.exports = AppDispatcher;
```

gulp is not starting it is throwing error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'react/lib/Object.assign' from '/Users/shanky-munjal/projects/testFlux/src/js/dispatchers'
    at /Users/shanky-munjal/projects/testFlux/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:46:17
    at process (/Users/shanky-munjal/projects/testFlux/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:173:43)
    at ondir (/Users/shanky-munjal/projects/testFlux/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:188:17)
    at load (/Users/shanky-munjal/projects/testFlux/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:69:43)
    at onex (/Users/shanky-munjal/projects/testFlux/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:92:31)
    at /Users/shankymunjal/projects/testFlux/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:22:47
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
```

I am using react 15.2.1

Comment: In `react/lib` there is no `Object.assign` file, you can use it `var assign = Object.assign;` because it is native `Object` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `Object.assign`

---

A long time ago **Dan Abramov** [wrote](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/718472855785193472):

> This is a gentle reminder that require('react/lib/SomeInternalModule')
>   in your component will break in some release regardless of semver.

Answer (score 0):

```
 npm install object-assign --save
```

this code will work

```
var assign = require("react/lib/Object.assign");
```

this code instead of

```
 var assign = require("Object-assign");
```